# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/jbox2d/callbacks/ContactFilter;

Tags: android, jbox2d

I have an android project and am trying to add JBox2D and added "jox2d-library-2.1.2.2.jar" as both a referenced library in Java Build Path|Libraries and via Android Dependencies and in both cases get the runtime error:

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/jbox2d/callbacks/ContactFilter;

I just don't understand why this is failing as there is only one instance of the JBox2D library jar added.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Each time before executing a run I perform a project clean.

Also, I have seen other Android developers have similar problems with different projects:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680 ... ternal-jar

and I have tried their suggestions but with no luck.

Graham

Answer (score -1):

if your ADT version 2.0 or higher lib file doesn t work.

Solution:
  -Delete lib file
  -Remove external jar file references from java build path
  -Create libs file 
  -Copy jar file here(don't reference from java build path)
  -Clean your project

Now it's ready for run